# Doctrine migrations with capifony on Jenkins box

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, capifony

I'm trying to deploy an Symfony2 application from a Jenkins box. I'm using capifony multistage deploy system for 2 differents environments: dev and uat.

When I put

```
before "symfony:cache:warmup", "symfony:doctrine:migrations:migrate"
```

on my dev.rb file I receive an error from capifony

```
`symfony:doctrine:migrations:migrate' is only run for servers matching {:roles=>:app, :only=>{:primary=>true}, :except=>{:no_release=>true}}, but no servers matched
```

How I can deploy and do migrations automatically with capifony?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed!

In your stage.rb file just add:

```
role    :app,               domain, :primary => true
```